# How best to terminate a python thread?

Tags: python, subprocess

In the code below I am creating a thread that opens up a function called candump. Candump monitors an input channel and returns values to std out as data comes in.

What I want to do is have control over when this terminates (ie, a fixed amount of time after cansend). After looking through the documentation it seems like join might be the right way to go?

I'm not sure. Any thoughts?

```
import threading
from subprocess import call, Popen,PIPE
import time

delay=1

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
  def run(self):
    start=time.time()
    proc=Popen(["candump","can0"],stdout=PIPE)
    while True:
        line=proc.stdout.readline()
        if line !='':
            print line

t = ThreadClass()
t.start()
time.sleep(.1)
call(["cansend", "can0", "-i", "0x601", "0x40", "0xF6", "0x60", "0x01", "0x00", "0x00", "0x00", "0x00"])
time.sleep(0.01)
#right here is where I want to kill the ThreadClass thread
```

Comment: There's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Are you asking how to terminate a thread, or are you asking how to put a timeout on a subprocess and you just thought thread termination was the way to do it? If the former, this is a dup of [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python). If the latter, it's not. (You _can_ terminate a _process_, which makes this easy.)

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess as sub
import threading

class RunCmd(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, cmd, timeout):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.timeout = timeout

    def run(self):
        self.p = sub.Popen(self.cmd)
        self.p.wait()

    def Run(self):
        self.start()
        self.join(self.timeout)

        if self.is_alive():
            self.p.terminate()
            self.join()

RunCmd(["./someProg", "arg1"], 60).Run()
```

---

cited from : [Python: kill or terminate subprocess when timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158502/python-kill-or-terminate-subprocess-when-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best way to terminate a thread, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14488766/216356) provides a way to kill a thread. Beware that you may also need to implement a way for threads to be unkillable in critical sections of their code.