# Python Threading, kill thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I want only one Thread to be active, here is the algorithm:

```
def myfunction(update):
    if threading.activeCount >=1:
        # kill all previous threads
    while true:
        # some execution


while true:
    t = threading.Thread(myfunction, args=([update]))
    t.start()
```

so In here thread goes in Infinite loop in myfunction, so before starting new one i need to close previous one, please guide me

Comment: did you check this out? https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join, and for the fun of it: http://bit.ly/1wDBDd9

Comment: @miraculixx i dont need to wait, i need to force thread to stop

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482230/why-does-the-python-threading-thread-object-has-start-but-not-stop

Comment: @Hackaholic you can't force it to stop from the outside, other than conditioning the loop, I was going to add an answer to that end, but since the question has been marked duplicate...

Comment: @miraculixx the problem is that, the while loop in function goes in infinite loop, so when next thread comes, i need to stop previous loop

Comment: @Hackaholic, try `while true and not stop_condition: ...`, then in your main thread before `t.start()` do `stop_condition = true` and `current_thread.wait(t)`. Not sure this works for you, you'd have to give more details on the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You can't kill threads, your function has to return somehow. The trick, then, is to write your function in such a way that it knows when to stop what its doing and return. That's very context dependent of course. Its common to implement your code as a class that has a 'close' method that knows what to do. For instance,

- if the thread is waiting on a subprocess, the close could kill the subprocess.
- If the thread does a sleep, you could use an event instead - the close would set the event.
- If your thread is waiting on a queue, you could have a special method that tells it to return.