# exit program stuck on sys.stdin.readline

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a thread waiting on input, but in the event that no input is provided, I need to exit the program. How can i exit the program? in this example the exit should be triggered by keyboard ctrl+c however I would also like to do this without interaction ie via a timeout or other event.

```
import threading
import signal
import sys
import time

shutdown = False

def shutdownHook(sigNum, currentStackFrame):
        global shutdown
        print('shutdown')
        shutdown = True

def readInput():
        print('readInput')
        print(sys.stdin.readline())
        print('done reading input')

if __name__ == '__main__':
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdownHook)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdownHook)

        inputThread = threading.Thread(name='input', target=readInput)
        inputThread.start()
        print('started input')

        while not shutdown:
                time.sleep(1)
                print('waiting ' + str(shutdown))
        print('current thread' + str(threading.current_thread()))
        print('end of program ' + str(shutdown))
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: can you see `done reading input` ?

Comment: i think the problem with the thread itself, lemme think more

Comment: `ctl+c` shows "shutdown", "waiting True", "current thread...", "end of program True" but doesn't exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`signal.alarm()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/signal.html#signal.alarm) to send a `SIGALRM` to your program after a certain amount of time (define here in second):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set the signal handler and a 5-second alarm
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, shutdownHook)
    signal.alarm(5)
```

Here is the [complete working example](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/signal.html#example) from the documentation:

> Here is a minimal example program. It uses the alarm() function to
>   limit the time spent waiting to open a file; this is useful if the
>   file is for a serial device that may not be turned on, which would
>   normally cause the os.open() to hang indefinitely. The solution is to
>   set a 5-second alarm before opening the file; if the operation takes
>   too long, the alarm signal will be sent, and the handler raises an
>   exception.

```
import signal, os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Signal handler called with signal', signum)
    raise OSError("Couldn't open device!")

# Set the signal handler and a 5-second alarm
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(5)

# This open() may hang indefinitely
fd = os.open('/dev/ttyS0', os.O_RDWR)

signal.alarm(0)          # Disable the alarm
```

As for why your program is not quitting is because [quoted the doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/signal.html#signals-and-threads)

> Python signal handlers are always executed in the main Python thread,
>   even if the signal was received in another thread. This means that
>   signals can’t be used as a means of inter-thread communication. You
>   can use the synchronization primitives from the threading module
>   instead. Besides, only the main thread is allowed to set a new signal handler.

That means your thread cannot receive no signals the way you design the program. In fact if you try to set a signal in your thread you will receive a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

That's why your program keeps turning after receiving a `SIGTERM`. Because the thread did not received the signal.

See here: [Kill python thread using os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633357/kill-python-thread-using-os) for alternative solution.

Answer (score -1):

Make the thread as Deamon thread, this way it will also shutdown when main thread is exited.

```
inputThread = threading.Thread(name='input', target=readInput)
inputThread.setDaemon(True) # add this line
inputThread.start()
```

Also you can add a time lapse for no activity within specified period.

```
time_limit_for_shutdown_in_secs = 10 
secs = 0
while not shutdown:
        if secs > time_limit_for_shutdown_in_secs: break
        time.sleep(1)
        print('waiting ' + str(shutdown))
        secs += 1

print('current thread' + str(threading.current_thread()))
print('end of program ' + str(shutdown))
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: this is wrong answer, you are not answering OP, you are just breaking the  loop! if you want not to be downvoted correct your answer

Comment: the requirement is to exit the program if in case no input was received for a certain amount of time

Comment: so you have not even run the code just once a time, the code stock when you enter the first input

Comment: the problem is not the loop, it is that sys.exit does not exit since stdin.readline is blocking.

Comment: Yes my bad, haven't noticed that it was indeed not exiting, i have updated my answer and this is currently working on my end.

Comment: it is not an answer yet, the problem is with threads ! not the while loop, it's about concurrency ! not just breaking a loop !!!

Comment: did you even tried running the updated code I provided? the question mentioned that other events include timeout so basically a limit of time should be achieved and program should exit thus the additional logic inside the loop, as for exiting the child thread I already updated my answer for that