# How to continuously flash LED (or other while loop) while Python code continues to run

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading, gpio

I would like to be able to flash an LED continuously while my main `while` loop continues. I understand that in the following code when the function `led_flash()` gets called, the script will stop until the `while` loop defined in the function ends. This prohibits the remainder of the code from running.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)

def led_flash():
    while TRUE:
        GPIO.output(25, ON)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(25, OFF)
        time.sleep(1)

while True:
    if x=1
        led_flash()
        ...do other stuff
```

I have read that threading will work in this instance, however I have not found an example simple enough for me to grasp. Additionally, if threading, how would I be able to end the `led_flash()` function thread later in my main `while` loop?

Comment: start a new thread would I suggest..

Comment: Start a new thread that performs `led_flash()`, then kill it in your main loop. A [Thread](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Threading) is an object which runs code from the `run` method when started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168508/background-function-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482230/why-does-the-python-threading-thread-object-has-start-but-not-stop) you can start a thread like this:

```
import threading
while True:
    if x = 1:
        flashing_thread = threading.Thread(target=led_flash)
        flashing_thread.start()
        #continue doing stuff
```

Since, in your case, you want to stop the thread (I assume if `x` doesn't equal `1`), then you can create a thread stopping class like so:

```
import threading
import sys

class StopThread(StopIteration): pass

threading.SystemExit = SystemExit, StopThread

class Thread2(threading.Thread):

    def stop(self):
        self.__stop = True

    def _bootstrap(self):
        if threading._trace_hook is not None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot run thread with tracing!')
        self.__stop = False
        sys.settrace(self.__trace)
        super()._bootstrap()

    def __trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        if self.__stop:
            raise StopThread()
        return self.__trace
```

And call it like: `flashing_thread.stop()`

Put it all together to get:

```
import threading
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

class StopThread(StopIteration): pass

threading.SystemExit = SystemExit, StopThread

class Thread2(threading.Thread):

    def stop(self):
        self.__stop = True

    def _bootstrap(self):
        if threading._trace_hook is not None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot run thread with tracing!')
        self.__stop = False
        sys.settrace(self.__trace)
        super()._bootstrap()

    def __trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        if self.__stop:
            raise StopThread()
        return self.__trace
#############################################################

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)

def led_flash():
    while TRUE:
        GPIO.output(25, ON)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(25, OFF)
        time.sleep(1)

# x gets defined somewhere

while True:
    if x == 1:
        flashing_thread = Thread2(target=led_flash)
        flashing_thread.start()
        #continue doing stuff
    else:
        if flashing_thread and flashing_thread.isAlive():
            flashing_thread.stop()
```

Comment: @cricket_007 It's part of the asker's code. The asker has defined it in their code and Ryan retained it for clarity (to the asker).

Comment: @Aaron3468 word. 
cricket_007 I added a comment for clarity regarding x.

Comment: Thank you, this is the most simple I have seen it explained. I assume I could also pass an argument to the thread to change the state of the LED (on, off, flashing) instead of stopping the thread.

Comment: @SpaceCase yes. A new thread with input arguments looks like: `flashing_thread = threading.Thread(target=led_flash, args=my_args)` where `my_args` is a tuple like `(arg1,arg2,)`.

Comment: Also, if this answer worked for you, do you mind accepting it?

Comment: @SpaceCase Very good observation! If you do choose to have a thread like that, you'll still need some way to end the (now rogue) thread when your program finishes/crashes or you will end up with a resource leak. Then your led will flash constantly and running the program again will result in a fight over led access. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635080/terminate-a-multi-thread-python-program). Don't forget to accept Ryan's answer :)

Comment: @ Ryan Schuster when I execute the code I get the error:      flashing_thread = threading.Thread2(target=flash_led)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Thread2'

Comment: @SpaceCase Typo on my account! It should be `Thread2(target=flash_led)` not `threading.Thread2(target=flash_led)` seeing as you've already defined the `Thread2` class yourself.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I am implementing this code on my PiBorg wheeled robot with a Raspberry Pi 3 board to switch on the yellow blinking light and keep moving. I had to change GPIO.output(25,ON) to GPIO.output(25, True), and also while TRUE to while True. So now the code works fine to switch on the blinking. However, I cannot stop blinking. The line of code: flashing_thread.stop() does not stop it for some reason. I have to restart Raspberry Pi 3 to stop it blinking. Python is a new language for me, and I cannot figure out so far how I can stop a blinking thread. I tried about everything already to no avail.

Comment: I solved the problem with blinking light on PiBorg & Raspberry Pi 3 wheeled robot with the code provided by Aaron3468 below. I added +1 to both solutions, as I still use .isAlive() from yours.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example after looking at the documentation:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def main_loop():
    mythread = LedThread()
    mythread.start()

    time.sleep(20) # execute while loop for 20 seconds
    mythread.stop()

class LedThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(LedThread, self).__init__()
        self._keepgoing = True

    def run(self):
        while (self._keepgoing):
            print 'Blink'
            time.sleep(0.5)


    def stop(self):
        self._keepgoing = False

main_loop()
```

Ideally, you should be using the `target` parameter from `threading.Thread.__init__`, because it allows you to push your function into the thread. Ryan Schuster's example is the more robust of the two, though I hope this one can help you understand what threads are by using only the basics necessary to run one.

Comment: +1 This code works just fine on my PiBorg & Raspberry Pi 3 wheeled robot. I can switch on the blinking light, keep moving, and switch off blinking.