# asyncore.loop doesn't terminate when there are no more connections

Tags: python, python-2.7, timeout, asyncore

I am following some example code to use `asyncore` [here](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/smtpd/), only having set a `timeout` value for `asyncore.loop` as in the following full example:

```
import smtpd
import asyncore

class CustomSMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        print 'Receiving message from:', peer
        print 'Message addressed from:', mailfrom
        print 'Message addressed to  :', rcpttos
        print 'Message length        :', len(data)
        return

server = CustomSMTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 1025), None)

asyncore.loop(timeout = 1)
```

I have expected that a timeout occurs after 1 second, but this is not the case. The code runs much longer for than one second. What am I missing here?

Comment: @pst: Count is not an option. I do not know if there will be zero or more than zero connections beforehand.

Comment: Then stop beating around the bush

Comment: @pst I do not know what you mean. My question is: Why does the timeout for `asyncore.loop()` does not end the function `asyncore.loop()` after the specified time.

Comment: Well, consider some cases: 1) the documentation is lying that it will stop running when there are no more open channels, 2) the documentation is lying about what the `timeout` does, 3) asyncore is not using the specified timeout with select 4) there *are* open channels .. I suspect it will end shortly if a count (say, 2) is specified. If that is indeed the case then #2 and #3 can likely be ruled out.

Comment: @pst: I do not understand what you mean. Maybe you could start answering the following question in a clear, concise and well-phrased answer: What is the purpose of the `timeout` argument in `asyncore.loop()`?

Comment: The documentation said what it does. Since *you* are making an assertion, I have provided some hypothesis to follow to verify or disprove said claim.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23246/discussion-between-alex-and-pst)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really do not know if the `timeout` argument to `asyncore.loop()` really is meant to timeout the function call `asyncore.loop()` after the specified time, but here is a receipt to make that function timeout after a specified time (replacing the line with `asyncore.loop()` in the example code):

```
import signal

class TimeoutError(Exception): pass

# define the timeout handler
def handler(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutError()

# set the timeout handler and the signal duration
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(1)
try:
    asyncore.loop()
except TimeoutError as exc:
    print "timeout"
finally:
    signal.alarm(0)
```

Comment: Note: not available on Windows with Python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

The `timeout` argument to `asyncore.loop()` is the amount of time the `select.select` call will wait for data. If there is no data before the `timeout` runs out it will loop and call `select.select` again.

Same for the `channels` idea. This does not mean open sockets but means active `asyncore.dispatcher` or `asynchat.async_chat` instances. If you want to stop the loop you will have to call the `close()` method on **ALL** instances registered.

In your case `server.close()` will close the instance/channel and remove it from the `asyncore` loop. If no more channels are active this loop will then terminate itself.

Comment: How can I call a `close` method if `asyncore.loop()` blocks my code?

Comment: @Alex You should either run the `asyncore.loop()` in a new thread or call the `close` inside one of the `handlers`. I don't know how you determine when to exit so if you tell us how you determine that we could help more.

Comment: I have been trying to run `asyncore.loop()` in a thread, see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483195/how-to-handle-asyncore-within-a-class-in-python-without-blocking-anything, but I need to figure out where and how to call `close` or how and where to modify any `hander` method. If you know how, I really would appreciate if you could elaborate this in the other question.

Comment: @Alex I posted an answer on the linked question. Please comment there if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout of asyncore.loop() is the timeout for select().

It is not useful, because when select() timeout, it loops back, see the pseudo code:

```
while True:
    do_something()
    select(...)
    do_something_else()
```

If I do simulation with firewall-ed sockets, in my Python 2.7.3 asyncore.loop() timeout 1 minute after no data is received from some socket.

I found very useful to have following method in asyncore.dispatcher "subclass":

```
def handle_error(self):
    raise
```

In this way I had "proper" exception dump.

Because I do not wanted to have exception, later I changed it to something like:

```
def handle_error(self):
    print "Error downloading %s" % self.host
    pass
```

Now my code works correct, without exception.

I did not found a way to control the timeout.