# How to scan python smtpd server for text

Tags: python, asyncore, smtpd

I would like to receive an email with python. Then I want to exit the mailserver and use the content of the email in my script.

For example:

```
if "any_string" in data:
    print "success"
    << exit mailserver >>
    << any other commands >>
```

Code:

```
import smtpd
import asyncore

class FakeSMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):
    __version__ = 'TEST EMAIL SERVER'

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        print 'Receiving message from:', peer
        print 'Message addressed from:', mailfrom
        print 'Message addressed to  :', rcpttos
        print 'Message length        :', len(data)
        print 'Message               :', data
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    smtp_server = FakeSMTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 25), None)
    try:
        asyncore.loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        smtp_server.close()
```

Comment: And the problem is ... ?

Comment: I do not know how to terminate the mailserver and how to scan the message for "any_string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exit from the `asyncore` loop by calling `asyncore.close_all` in you `process_message` method :

```
def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
    # ...
    print 'Message               :', data
    asyncore.close_all()
    return
```

EDIT

If you want to have access to the text of the message after exiting from `asyncore` loop, you simply store it as an attribute of your smtp server

```
#...
class FakeSMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):
    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        # ...
        self.data = data
        # ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    smtp_server = FakeSMTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 25), None)
    try:
        asyncore.loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        smtp_server.close()
    # smtp_server.data contains text of message
```

Comment: Very good. Thanks :) but how I get data (the message) into a variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SMTP.quit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.quit) for closing the SMTP session. In your case you can use it like `smtp_server.quit()`

Regarding searching a word in a string you can do so

```
data = 'my Test data'
for word in data.split():
    if 'test' in word:
        print "success"
```

If you want to ignore the case (uppercase/lowercase) then simply convert the string to lowercase using [lower()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lower) and then check as shown below:

```
data = 'my Test data'
for word in data.lower().split():
    if 'test' in word:
        print "success"
```

If you want to stop the script while using the `asyncore.loop()` then you may need to use a different thread to start the SMTP server and then you can control it. This question explains the details. [How to handle asyncore within a class in python, without blocking anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483195/how-to-handle-asyncore-within-a-class-in-python-without-blocking-anything)

Comment: Thanks, but where I can use "smtp_server.quit()"? The Script is in the asyncore.loop()