# Python asyncore.loop in client

Tags: python, sockets, asyncore

I've googled many articles, but still without significant information.

My question is about how to stop asyncore.loop() in client side.

My code is the following
import socket, asyncore

```
class Client(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.buffer = ''
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)

        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect((host, port))

    def writable(self):
        return len(self.buffer) > 0

    def handle_connect(self):
        print "handle_connect"

    def handle_close(self):
        print "handle_close"
        self.close()

    def handle_write(self):
        print "handle_write"
        sent = self.send(self.buffer)
        self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]
        print sent

    def command(self, data):
        self.buffer = data

    def close(self):
        self.close()


mysocket = Client("127.0.0.1", 8888)
mysocket.command("asfas\n")

asyncore.loop()

mysocket.close()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to stop a loop? You want to complete some actions after the stopping?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490077/how-to-quit-an-asyncore-dispatcher-from-a-handler  - I think, it will be helpful for you

Comment: Thank you for comment @Dmitry. I need it, because this is client, and after running commands the client script should exit. Your second comment is for server side.